# while executing Alter query I am getting this error

Tags: python, testing, libvlc, ignition

```
ALTER TABLE TRN_Testdata
    ADD ":columnName" varchar(50) null;
```

I am getting this error:

```
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.client.gateway_interface.GatewayInterface.newGatewayException(GatewayInterface.java:339)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.client.gateway_interface.GatewayInterface.sendMessage(GatewayInterface.java:313)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.client.gateway_interface.GatewayInterface.sendMessage(GatewayInterface.java:266)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.client.gateway_interface.GatewayInterface.invoke(GatewayInterface.java:915)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.designer.db.namedquery.workspace.NamedQueryTestingPanel$1$1.doInBackground(NamedQueryTestingPanel.java:313)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.designer.db.namedquery.workspace.NamedQueryTestingPanel$1$1.doInBackground(NamedQueryTestingPanel.java:288)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.db.namedquery.NamedQueryExecutor$NamedQueryInstance.execute(NamedQueryExecutor.java:413)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.db.namedquery.NamedQueryExecutor.execute(NamedQueryExecutor.java:199)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.db.namedquery.GatewayNamedQueryManager.execute(GatewayNamedQueryManager.java:117)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.servlets.gateway.functions.NamedQueryFunctions.executeNamedQuery(NamedQueryFunctions.java:67)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(null)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(null)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.servlets.gateway.AbstractGatewayFunction.invoke(AbstractGatewayFunction.java:225)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.servlets.Gateway.doPost(Gateway.java:412)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.inductiveautomation.ignition.gateway.bootstrap.MapServlet.service(MapServlet.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(null)
```

- Ignition v8.0.12 (b2020042115)
- Java: Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Using Ignition's Data Base Query Browser Tool - Give this a try

```
ALTER TABLE 'table name' ADD 'new column name' VARCHAR[50] AFTER 'existing column name'.
```